# curl email error mailer.php

Tags: php, html, curl

I have a mailer.php on our site that connects with sendgrid to send us emails from a enquiry form. However on our setup when someone types in a question to email they receive a error page when they click send. Ironically the email still gets sent but its not fowarding them to the success page on our server.

Below is the error message you receive.

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/dekastud/public_html/mailer.php on line 35

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dekastud/public_html/mailer.php:1) in /home/dekastud/public_html/mailer.php on line 53

```html
    <?php
// use actual sendgrid username and password in this section
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
$user = '***'; // place SG username here
$pass = '***'; // place SG password here

// grabs HTML form's post data; if you customize the form.html parameters then you will need to reference their new new names here
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];


// note the above parameters now referenced in the 'subject', 'html', and 'text' sections
// make the to email be your own address or where ever you would like the contact form info sent
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "***", // set TO address to have the contact form's email content sent to
    'subject'   => "Contact Form Submission From ***", // Either give a subject for each submission, or set to $subject
    'html'      => "<html><head><title> Contact Form</title><body>
    Name: $name\n<br>
    Email: $email\n<br>
    Subject: $subject\n<br>
    Message: $message <body></title></head></html>", // Set HTML here.  Will still need to make sure to reference post data names
    'text'      => "
    Name: $name\n
    Email: $email\n
    Subject: $subject\n
    $message",
    'from'      => "***", // set from address here, it can really be anything
  );


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// Redirect to thank you page upon successfull completion, will want to build one if you don't alreday have one available
header('Location: /thankyou.html'); // feel free to use whatever title you wish for thank you landing page, but will need to reference that file name in place of the present 'thanks.html'
exit();

// print everything out
print_r($response);?>
```

Comment: post the top part. The headers already sent error means you have already sent something to the browser

Comment: you also have a `curl_setopt()` call before your `curl_init()`

Comment: full mailer.php added with sensitive information replaced with ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space at the top of the PHP file. Those couple of spaces before the `<?php` actually send output to the browser. Once something is output to the browser, you cannot send headers.

`header("Location: ...");`

is sending a header...

Also, you have a `curl_setopt()` call before a call to `curl_init()`, which is invalid. `curl_setopt()` requires a valid curl resources. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);` should go below the call to `curl_init()` and the `$curl` variable should be replaced with a valid curl resource, or in your case, `$session`.